# Is it possible to temporarily hide a file from any system call in linux?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, fuse

I am trying to implement a filesystem by using FUSE, and i want the file to get hidden temporarily when it is deleted. I tried to store all the files' name or its inode in an array and check them when some system call like 'open' , 'getattr' or 'readdir' get invoked. But it could eat up tons of performance when the number gets really huge. So i wonder is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So your question is "how do I store and quickly search a huge pile of numbers"? Binary search tree or hashtable. You can probably implement a BST (AVL tree?) after reading up on it, for a hashtable I would recommend looking around for a library that would do that for you.

Comment: If you *really* implement the FS yourself, you could *maybe* implement it yourself? [this would need an extra API call]

Comment: If you unlink a file from the directory, but still have it open, then its space is not released and open calls will not find it. Another solution might be to leave it in a directory but remove all permissions from the directory.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! It seems 'setxattr' can get this done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, when unlink is called, you want the file to be marked as deleted rather than actually deleted.
You could implement this mark as an extended attribute, one with "system" namespace (see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7.html) which is not listed as part of the file xattr list.
In your "unlink", do setxattr(system.markdelete). In all of your other calls with path arg, and in readdir, getxattr and treat it as deleted.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i have been searching for!

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems to your approach  (and to the solution pointed out by Oren Kishon, and marked as selected):

- first is that a file has no name *per se*.  The name of a file is not part of the file.  The mapping of filenames to files (actually to inodes) is created by the system for the comodity of the user, but the names are completely independent of the files they point to.  This means that you know easily which is the inode a link points to, but it is very difficult to do the reverse mapping (getting the directory entry that points to the inode, with just knowing the inode)  The deletion of a file is a two phase process.  In the first phase, you call `unlink(2)` system call to erase a link (to erase a directory entry) from the directory it belongs, and then deallocate all the blocks pertaining to that file, **but only in case the reference count (which is stored in the inode itself) drops to zero.**  This is an easy process, as everything starts from the directory entry you want to be deleted.  But if you dont erase it, searching for it later will be painfull, as you can see below, in the second problem stated here.
- Second is that if you do this with, let's say, six links (hard links) to the same file, you'll never know, when you need the space to be actually reallocated to another file (because you run out of unallocated space) because the link reference count is still six on the inode.  Even worse, if you add a second ref count in the inode to follow the (different) number of truly erased files that have not yet been unallocated, the problem is that you have to search over the whole filesystem.(because you have no idea on where should the links be)  So you need to maintain a lot of information (to add to the space the file occupies in the filesystem) first to gather all the links that pointed once to this file, and second to check if this is indeed the file that has to be deallocated, in case more space is needed in the filesystem.

By the way, your problem has an easy solution in user space, although.  Just modify the `rm` command to never erase a file completely(e.g. never unlink the last link to a file), but to move the files in a queue in some fixed directory in the same filesystem in which the file resided, to handle the last link to it, and this will maintain the files still allocated (but you lose any reference, or you can save it in an associated file, to the name of the file).  A monitor process can check the amount of free space and select from the queue the first one (*erased* oldest), and truly erase it.  Beware that if you have large files erased, this will make your system load to grow at random times when it is time to actually erase the files you are deallocating.

There's another alternative.  Use **zfs** as your filesystem.  This requires a lot of memory and cpu, but is a complete solution to the undeletion of files, because zfs conserves the full history of the filesystem, so you can get back in time upto a snapshot in which the file existed, and then make a copy of it, actually recovering it.  ZFS can be used on WORM(Write Once Read Many, as DVD) media and this allows you to conserve the filesystem state over time (at the expense of never reusing the same data again)  But you will never lose a file.

#### Edit

There's one case in which the file is no longer available to use for any other process than the ones that have it open.  In this scenario, one process opens a file, then deletes it (deletion involves just breaking the link that allows to translate the name of the file to the inode in the system) but continues using the file, until it finally closes.

As you probably know, a file can be opened by several files at the same time.  Apart from the number of references that figures in the disk inode, there's a number of references to the inode in the inode table in kernel memory.  This is the number of references of the file in the disk inode (the number of directory entries that point to the file's inode) plus one reference for each file entry that states a file is open.

When a file is unlinked (and it should be deleted, because no more links to the inode are referencing it) the deallocation doesn't take immediately, as the file is still being used by processes.  The file is alive, although it doesn't appear in the filesystem (there's no more references to it in any directory)  Only when the last `close(2)` of the file takes place, the file is deallocated in the system.

But what happened to the directory entry that referenced las that file.  It can be reused (as I told you in one of the comments) immediately it has been freed, long before the file is deallocated.  A new file (it will be forcibly a different inode, as the old one is still in use) will be created and named as the original one (because you decided to name it the same) and no problem is on this, but that you are using a different file.  The old file is still in use, and has no name, and for this reason is unvisible to other processes except the one that is using it.  This technique is used frequently to use temporary files, in which you create a file with `open(2)`, and immediately `unlink(2)` it.  No other process can access that file, and that file will be deallocated as soon as the file entry is `close(2)`d.  But such a file will be deallocated as soon as the last `close(2)` on it is called.  No file of this characteristics can survive a reboot of the system. (it cannot even survive the process that had it open)

As the question states:

> Is it possible to temporarily hide a file from any system call in linux?

The file is hidden to all the system calls that require a name for the file (it has no name anymore) but not to other system calls (e.g. `fstat(2)` continue to work, while `stat(2)` will be impossible to use on that file, same with `link(2)`, `rename(2)`, `open(2)`, etc.)

Comment: Thank you. Another simple case of inconsistency I thought of. What happens if after deletion the user creates a new file with the same name? Where is the data stored? This is taken care of in your solution of a trash folder

Comment: normally, if a new file is created after one is deleted with the same name, it will probably get a different inode (every file has only one inode) or the same, depending on the number of available inodes.  This new file has nothing to do with the old one, it is a completely different file.  While a file is deleted, the inode is locked, so only one process can act on it.  And the file deletion is probably the most costly operation in the system.

Comment: In the sense of availability (as your question stated) there's no lack of availability, as the name is available for reuse even before the actual deallocation of blocks in the old deleted file is finished.

Comment: If I got the situation of this question right, the backend file system is managed by paths, so the claim "This new file has nothing to do with the old one" doesn't apply - on a call to open(create) on the same name by the user (new from the user POV), the fuse backend will have to call open(create) on the still not unlinked backend path.

Comment: @OrenKishon, the backend filesystem is managed by inodes.  All filesystems are managed by inodes (some systems call them vnodes) and the requirement of the names not being part of the file is esential to provide multiple links to a single file.  You cannot `open`/`create` a file without a path, and the hidden files I mention in my answer don't have a path, so you cannot open them.  The mark you propose is already in the filesystem, it is the `st_nref` field of the inode, and the way you can hold it is to actually have a second link to a private place...

Comment: This is the only way you can restore the file back to the file system.  Once a file has lost its last link, there's no way back to create a linx to it again.

Comment: I was referring to the situation of the original answer, where deleted files are not unlinked or moved, but marked with setxattr.

Comment: Yeah... but, as I post in my answer and the user agrees with, that situation is not possible because if you repeat it for several links to the same file, then you have to search all the filesystem to find the directory that holded the link to the file to recover it.  And you need some way to locate the file, which without a name is for now impossible.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer, and sorry for my late reply, i think i didnt correctly describe the question. My intention is somewhat simlilar to the zfs, i want to create a filesystem(mfs) to mirror an existing filesystem (like ext4), the filesystem(ext4) being mirrored will be protected no matter how i screw up mfs. if i understand correctly, the first solution you gave would make change to (remove) the directory entry, which i dont want that to happen to the original filesystem(ext4).

Comment: zfs has nothing to do with the classical design of unix filesystems.  Neither ext* not ufs, sysvfs or the like has anything in common with zfs.